# What is to use commas and apostrophes?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, apostrophe

> "Halloween: the one day where we encourage children to accept candy from strangers, go to strangers' homes, and vandalize property and terrorize people if they don't get their own way."

Original quote by Yvette Colomb

I also notice grammar checks often rebuke my apostrophe placements.

I am wondering if there is a missing comma and if the apostrophe at *strangers* is correct. Does it have to include an apostrophe for ownership?

I tend to overdo it with commas, and restricted myself this time.

the *vandalize property and terrorize people if they don't get their own way*

is an inclusive point after the other list items.

Usually I would write:

> the one day where we encourage children to accept candy from strangers, go to strangers' homes,  vandalize property, and terrorize people if they don't get their own way.

which is not the same thing or:

> the one day where we encourage children to accept candy from strangers, go to strangers' homes, and  vandalize property and terrorize people if they don't get their own way.

Which is the best or most correct way (if there is one) to write this?

Comment: The apostrophe is fine in its place. There are no grammar issues. Commas are not strictly grammar. Proof-reading is incidentally off topic on ELU.

Comment: The punctuation issue is nothing to do with commas or apostrophes, neither of which address the elephant in the room (some form of punctuation is required between the first two words).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: what elephant would that be?  I don't see one in this sentence, either figuratively or literally.  The sentence looks just fine, to me.  As far as the apostrophe is concerned, there is some disputation over whether that *strangers’* should be followed by an "s".  Strunk says it should, but others not.  My Microsoft Word grammar checker likes *strangers'* but not *strangers’s*.  I am unsure, but tend nowadays to forget the possessive ending with an -s.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I omitted the colon after Halloween: and edited it after FF's comment cheers.. is this Q on topic?

Comment: I think it *is* on-topic.  I don't think this is proof-reading, @Kris.  Skippy is asking about something written by someone else in a publication, not asking for proof-reading he/she wrote him/herself.  Sorry, Skip, don't know your gender.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist erm, I did write it. But it is a question I have wanted to ask with reference to both.

Comment: I stand corrected!  Interesting sentence and definition of Halloween.  I take you are Yvette, then.  Cool.

Comment: You're missing an apostrophe in ***Hallowe'en***. Otherwise, the sentence is perfectly correct and gets its points across exactly as you intend. Never ever trust software grammar checkers.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I was wondering about that! sometimes I think they're wrong and they've got me doubting myself... hm.. not ofay with Hallowe'en, we're in Australia and it's only recently taken off

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I have wanted to ask this type of Q for a while, but making a public quote, pressed me to check my thinking.. which is good, because it's been increasingly bothering me with the use of the internet etc

Comment: @AndrewLeach, in the US the accepted spelling of Hallowe'en is Halloween.  I hardly ever see it spelled any other way, here.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Are you sure Strunk wants an "s" after the apostrophe? After all, "strangers" is a plural noun. I thought the only controversy here involving Strunk was whether an "s" is needed when forming the possessives of *singular* nouns that end in "s". For example, are my things Andreas's or Andreas'?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Upon further checking, Strunk doesn't address the possessive of plural nouns.  See here: http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html  But in the case of Andreas, it is "Andreas's things".  Note that Strunk's work is a "manual of style", not the be-all and end-all of English grammar.  There are numerous rulebooks of style; I just happen to like Strunk's (and White's).

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Thanks for checking. I agree with Strunk & White about "Andreas's" and even about "Blass's", but I notice that some entirely competent writers of English disagree.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I asked this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138202/the-use-of-apostrophes-to-denoted-ownership-on-plurals as I am now curious to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence as written is perfectly correct, and not only that, it is quite clear and well-written.  It makes interesting and humorous points about Hallowe'en.  There is some ambivalence about the spelling of Halloween, but that's because of that darned apostrophe.  In the US (and possibly Canada?) the apostrophe is largely dropped, but is still the rule in the UK.

Comment: thanks, I find the longer I'm online the more doubts I have about my grammar

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138202/the-use-of-apostrophes-to-denoted-ownership-on-plurals

Answer (score 1):

"Halloween, the day we..." would be equally grammatically correct, and I personally promote the use of commas in substitution of colons.

Comment: thank you Jacob, that is something I also think about +1

Answer (score 1):

The sentence looks fine, but let me just emphasize that adding a comma after "property" would change the meaning (and would make the "and" before "vandalize" superfluous); it would limit the scope of "if they don't get their own way" to just the "terrorize" part, rather than the "vandalize ... and terrorize" part.  (I assume this is what you meant by "which is not the same thing", but I want to make the difference completely explicit.)